# Dynamic insert fails in groovy SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, groovy, insert

I'm trying to insert into my table a dynamic input.

```
def SYS_idValue = '9999999'

try{
    //Open connection to CCM
    connection = Sql.newInstance(CCMJdbcUrl, CCMUsername, CCMPassword, CCMJdbcDriver)

    def Mytable = 'INSERT INTO INTELTABLE (SYS_ID) VALUES (?)'
    connection.execute Mytable, [${SYS_idValue}]
       
    connection.close()
        
}  catch (Exception e) {
    println("Exception" + e)
    connection.close()
}
```

I'm reading this useful documentation:
https://livebook.manning.com/book/groovy-in-action-second-edition/chapter-13/106

But can't figure it out.
No errors so far, but don't work

This method works but i have to define the input.

```
connection.execute """INSERT INTO INTELTABLE (SYS_ID)
                    values ('3333333')"""
```

Any ideas?
Thank you guys!

Comment: If you really don't get any sort of error with this, you should take a good look at the environment you are running this and why it is so. If you don't get compile errors maybe something refuses silently to reload/use that code and eats the error.

Comment: My dear @cfrick 

Yes, I will take a closer look into my debugger.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing won't even compile:

```
connection.execute Mytable, [${SYS_idValue}]
```

Possible options are:

```
connection.execute Mytable, [ SYS_idValue ]
//or
connection.execute Mytable, [ "${SYS_idValue}" ]
```

Comment: 2nd option worked perfectly. 

Now i added one more input this way!
connection.execute Mytable, [ SYS_ID ] + [ firstname1 ]

Thank you a lot for your time.!!

Comment: `[SYS_ID, firstname1]` should do too then.

Comment: @cfrick yes!! Thank you